# application not supported error while installing signed app

Tags: code-signing, nokia, java-me, midp

I signed the application and trying to install on Nokia 5000 giving error "Application not supported".
and failing download of application.

I used the MIDP 2.0 and have given following application permission 
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.read, javax.microedition.io.Connector.http, javax.microedition.io.Connector.socket, javax.microedition.media.control.RecordControl

when i am changing permission as following application able to download and at last when download finished download exit as error 
"Invalid applicaion".
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.read, javax.microedition.io.Connector.http, javax.microedition.io.Connector.socket
MIDlet-Permissions-Opt: javax.microedition.media.control.RecordControl

I am able to install and run unsigned application on this model.

Help me out here .

Thanks
Sohil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

I think your suggestion is right here .

> I'm guessing some of the permissions
>   you listed is not supported by the
>   phone. This is the reason for the
>   initial "application not supported"
>   error.

Record functionality is not supported in 5000 so following permission is not compatible with this phone. 
javax.microedition.media.control.RecordControl

So i have to create the separate build particular for this model without this permission and also i have to remove the media control reference from the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understood your question, but here's something to check:

I'm guessing some of the permissions you listed is not supported by the phone. This is the reason for the initial "application not supported" error.

I also have a theory about the "invalid application" error. The MIDlet permissions are listed both in the JAD file and in the manifest file inside the JAR. For signed applications, the entries in the JAD and JAR manifest must be identical. Mismatch here is a common cause for the "invalid application" error you mention. If you try to modify the permissions from the JAD of a signed MIDlet, you would most probably receive this error. Because the JAR is signed and can't be modified, changing the permissions is not possible after signing.